# Universal Google Analytics virtual pageview location

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

**Situation**

On our site we implement virtual pageviews for ajax filters and page scrollings.

When user open Rent page on our site:

- real url: "/rent"
- send to GA:

  ```
  ga("send", "pageview", {page: "/rent/"})
  ```

When user scroll to second page:

- we change real url via js: "/rent/?page=2"
- send to GA (we care only about main page):

  ```
  ga("send", "pageview", {page: "/rent/"})
  ```

Or when user drills down:

- we change real url via js: "/rent/appartment/?page=2"
- send to GA (we care about path):

  ```
  ga("send", "pageview", {page: "/rent/appartment"})
  ```

But we noticed that really GA code does not take current real url (window.location) each time we call `ga`, but uses first time location. So when user drill down GA code send:

```
    GET collect?...&t=pageview&dl=http://example.com/rent&dp=/rent/appartment&...
    ....
    Referrer: http://example.com/rent/appartment
```

Here `dl` parameter is location of our page (not really current location) and `dp` is a page parameter in `ga` call. Notice that referrer is ok.

We decided to provide `ga` with real location (like in referrer) and change code to:

```
    ga("send", "pageview", {page: "/rent/appartment", location: "http://example.com/rent/appartment"})
```

**Problem**

From now on I was satisfied, but was not guys that uses GA to analyze Paid Search effectiveness: bounce rate raised drammaticaly (something like 20% to 70%).

Drilling to the problem I've noticed that GA "loses" user when we remove campaign  parameters (`utm...`) and send location without them.

**Questions**

Should I care about real location in this situation? How does location affects pageviews? How can I workaround or solve this problem?

**Additional information**

Seems like the main problem is that we drop CPC parameters when we change `location` for GA:

1. landing page: /rent?utm_source=...&... (or gclid for Google)
2. scroll down to second page: /rent?page=2 - there are no CPC parameters.

Additional information here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1714454?hl=en

But I'm still can't figure out an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4):

When you send a hit to GA with analytics.js, it's going to send the data it has stored on the tracker object that you created when you invoked `ga('create', ...);`. You can override those values by passing in an object (as you did), but if no overrides are specified, that tracker data is used.

When the tracker object is created it collects data about the current page (e.g. url, title, window size, etc) and stores that information. It does *not* recollect that info before you send hits. You have to update it if that data changes.

That means if you're updating the page information in an AJAX site and want analytics.js to "remember" that you've updated the page, you'll have to set it on the tracker. The advantage to setting it on the tracker is that if you send other hit types (e.g. events, social, exceptions), you won't have to specify those new values each time.

So, instead of doing:

```
ga("send", "pageview", {page: "/rent/appartment"})
```

Do this:

```
ga("set", {page: "/rent/appartment"});
ga("send", "pageview");
```

Now, if you send an event later, the event will be associated with the apartment page.

**UPDATE:** there is now an official guide for how to properly [track single page applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) with Google Analytics.

Comment: Hm. Ok, now I have original bounce level, but location for page remains unchanged. Seems it's the same as: `ga("send", "pageview", {page: "/rent/appartment"})`. But what about location?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same, except for when you're sending non-pageview hits. If you want location to update too, then you can set that as well. `ga('set', {location: 'http://example.com/rent/apartment', page: '/rent/apartment'});`. Also, if you **really** want to see what's going on under the hood, use the [debug version](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug) of analytics.js